# PayPal IPN simuator not working?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am tryin gto insert a new entry into my database when a transaction is Completed. So I have created this IPN Listener Script on my Server:

```
    <?php

include 'MessageManager.php';

// STEP 1: read POST data
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

if (preg_match("!(VERIFIED)\s*\Z!",$res)){
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $quantity = $_POST['custom'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];

    if($payment_status === "Completed"){
        addMessage($item_name,(int) $quantity , $payment_amount);
    } else {
    }

} else {
}
?>
```

Which is based on the script provided by PayPal. I am using the IPN simulator to test the script. The script is supposed to insert a new entry into my Database upon completion of the sale. The insertion code works well by itself, however when i run the simulator, it says success on the paypal sute, however there is no new entry in my database.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I am getting this Error Message:

> Failed 1SSL certificate problem

Than you for your Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning the ssl verify option off. I checked my IPN script and it's off there. There's [some caveats](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/) to this but it should be safe since you're connecting to PayPal and verifying the data.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Ok that works :) But that does arry some security issues. But as you said its safe. Thank you